# Using sublime Text 3 theme with c9

Tags: themes, c9.io

Is it possible to import the highlighting and theme of the sublime editor into c9 ? I really like the looks of it and i am used to it, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The theme used by sublime text 3 is, "Monokai". So you have to go into "View" inside your editor, then hover over "themes". There will then be a pop-up showing all of the themes, there are many to choose from, and you don't necessarily need to apply the "Monokai" theme.

P.S. This is for the OLD c9 as I received access from an online course I am doing. I hope this answer helped!!